# Add post variables to form send with FormData() via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, post

Because I want attach files to upload I'm trying to send a form using `new FormData(myForm)`, however I want to add to post some data which not coming from the form.

Previously before I needed to upload file I used `serializeArray()` and it was pretty easy to add some data to array.

I know that I can add some hidden inputs but I don't like this solution.

Is there any better solution to manipulate form data before send it with `FormData()`?

Comment: `FormData.append()`, as described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `FormData.append()`. It's described in the [`FormData API documentation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)